# Multi Layer JSON for AngularJS ng-repeat format

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, traversal

My Data looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "TravelerExtended": {
      "ExtendedInt_1": {
        "#text": "0",
        "Label": "Do you require the hotel has a spa or fitness center?:"
      },
      "ExtendedInt_2": {
        "#text": "0",
        "Label": "Do you prefer to be prechecked into your room?:"
      },
      "ExtendedInt_3": {
        "#text": "0",
        "Label": "Connecting/Adjoining rooms, when traveling with family?:"
      },
```

Then, my $scope is this:

```
define(function () {
    return function ($scope, $ticket, $person, $http, $el, $app) {
        // TODO

    $scope.is_loading = true;

    var params = {
        url: "http://10.100.1.98:81/myidapi.php",

        // Any other parameters will be sent as-is
        // to your remote web service.
        // For example, here we are sending an 'email' parameter:
        id: $ticket.id
    };

    $http.get('DP_URL/agent/misc/proxy', {params: params}).success(function(data) {
        $scope.is_loading = false;
        $scope.profiles = data;

    });    


    };

});
```

Then, of course, I have the HTML output trying to use the various NG functions:

```
<div ng-repeat="traveler in profiles">
        Extended Profile
    <div ng-repeat="profile in traveler.TravelerExtended"> 
        <li ng-repeat-"field in profile.ExtendedInt_1">
         {{field.label}} {{field.#text}}
        </li>
    </div>
</div>
```

I can't seem to figure out how to get to the third level of data.  It seems that that perhaps the initial data load is malformed, or that I just am bungling up the ng-repeat functions.

Comment: The permisible parents of a `<li>` element do not include the `<div>` element. See [MDN HTML Reference - `<li>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/li).

Comment: `field.#text` is illegal syntax. One needs to use bracket syntax property accessor: `field['#text']`. For more information, see [MDN JavaScript Reference - property accessors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors).

Answer (score 1):

`ng-repeat` works on array... in the data structure which you pasted, you got one array only (`profiles`) and within it an object (`TravelerExtended`) within which there are 3 more objects (`ExtendedInt_1, ExtendedInt_2, ExtendedInt_3`).

To traverse them, you need to work within a single `ng-repeat` (because you have one array only). The following code does the traversing for the data structure you pasted.

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.records = [
    "Alfreds Futterkiste",
    "Berglunds snabbköp",
    "Centro comercial Moctezuma",
    "Ernst Handel",
  ]

  $scope.profiles = [{
      "TravelerExtended": {
        "ExtendedInt_1": {
          "text": "0",
          "Label": "Do you require the hotel has a spa or fitness center?:"
        },
        "ExtendedInt_2": {
          "text": "0",
          "Label": "Do you prefer to be prechecked into your room?:"
        },
        "ExtendedInt_3": {
          "text": "0",
          "Label": "Connecting/Adjoining rooms, when traveling with family?:"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "TravelerExtended": {
        "ExtendedInt_1": {
          "text": "0",
          "Label": "2 Do you require the hotel has a spa or fitness center?:"
        },
        "ExtendedInt_2": {
          "text": "0",
          "Label": "2 Do you prefer to be prechecked into your room?:"
        },
        "ExtendedInt_3": {
          "text": "0",
          "Label": "2 Connecting/Adjoining rooms, when traveling with family?:"
        }
      }
    }
  ];

  /*
  for(var i=0; i<$scope.profiles.length; i++){
    console.log($scope.profiles[0].TravelerExtended);
    console.log($scope.profiles[0].TravelerExtended.ExtendedInt_1);
  }
  */

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

  <div ng-repeat="traveler in profiles">
    {{traveler.TravelerExtended.ExtendedInt_1.Label}} {{traveler.TravelerExtended.ExtendedInt_1.text}} <br/>
    {{traveler.TravelerExtended.ExtendedInt_2.Label}} {{traveler.TravelerExtended.ExtendedInt_2.text}} <br/>
    {{traveler.TravelerExtended.ExtendedInt_2.Label}} {{traveler.TravelerExtended.ExtendedInt_2.text}} <hr/>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

What said from Akber is right. If you need to cycle automatically inside your object you could do something like this:

```
$http.get('DP_URL/agent/misc/proxy', {params: params}).success(function(data) {
       $scope.is_loading = false;
       $scope.profiles = formatData(data);

   });    
formatData(dataObject) {
       var dataArray = [];
       angular.forEach(dataObject, function(value, key) {
               dataArray.push(value);
       });
       return dataArray;
   }
```